# Javafx button doesn't respond after first call (I call methode in task thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I have initialized parseBtn onAction but because the work in parseFunction will be more than one minute I created Task to do the work in new Thread(task).start() the function is working in background will but after finishing parseBtn doesn't respond any more.

I think because the work in another thread the button doesn't notify that work finished

```java
@FXML private Button parseBtn;

public void initialize(){

        parseBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                new Thread(task).start();
            }
        });
}

Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            //do something

            return null;
        }
};
```

the process inside the task is done but the button doesn't respond any more

Comment: Nothing about this short fragment of code should cause an application to hang.  Please edit your question and include a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `Task` is not designed to be run multiple times. It is certainly not intended to be run from multiple threads at once. (This would result in issues with the `state` property.) [`Service`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) may be used to implement this kind of functionality. However as you can see in the example in the javadoc, there is a method that is used to create a new instance of `Task`...

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. you are right I changed my code by creating new class extend Thread then call start from class instance as in the answer

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution my mistake was that task can't be calling multiple time.

```
    class parser extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
                //work to do
        }
    }

   public void initialize(){
        parseBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                parser p = new parser();
                p.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you are using a `Controller` that extends `Thread`. I would guess that this is a terrible coding idea. I am not advanced enough to know for sure, but it just does not seem right.

Comment: @Sedrick actually the controller doesn't extend a controller inside the controller I have create a new class that extends Thread .. in your opinion How I can  do this task?